# Replying to tweets using the twitteR package in R

Tags: r, twitter, bots, twitter-r

I'm trying to build a twitter bot with this general functionality: people tweet at my account, I do some natural language processing, and reply to their tweet with some results. What I'm not able to find in the `twitteR` package is a function that retrieves tweets that have been made directly at your account. Does this exist, or am I supposed to use a combination of the other functions in the package? Haven't been able to do it using the other functions.

Comment: This problem description seems, what's the right word... nondescript? At least it's nondescript in the sense of having no code, no sample data and an extremely vague description of what the results should be. Request for package recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: @42- fair enough, but how would you do it differently in this case? The question is asking for a function that does a specific act, an act that is much easier explained by words ("tweets at an account") than by adding a whole block of code beforehand. Adding sample data feels unnecessary IMO. And it's not asking fora package recommendation, but for a specific function inside a specific package that I've provided (twitteR). Not sure if that is still considered off-topic.